# Find the value of the angle $X$ in the given figure

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, angle

In this picture, the curve in the inside of the big outer triangle is actually its incircle. The edges of the triangle inside the incircle are the intersections of the incircle with the outer triangle.

[image: FindAngle]

What is the value of angle $X$ in the given figure?

Comment: $x=\frac{180-64}2$

Comment: Information given is incomplete - what relation does the inner triangle have with the outer?

Comment: Roman83, what is this formula? Could you explain

Comment: abiessu, it is a circle.

Comment: Okay, so are the corner points of the inner triangle supposed to be on the edges of the outer triangle?  It seems that at least one isn't quite lining up that way...

Comment: I am on @Roman83 's side. From the center of the circle, draw three lines to the corners of the inner triangle, and note that these three lines are perpendicular to the sides of the outer triangle and have the same length

Comment: I still can not understand why he did 180 - 64

Comment: Changed Y-axis scale, hope OK.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use the notation as in this picture.
[image: triangle]

Note that  $\overline{DE} \perp \overline{BC}$ and $\overline{DG} \perp \overline{AC}$.
Hence $\angle GDE= 180-\angle EBG$.
AS the traingle $\triangle GED$ is isosceles, we conclude $$\angle DEG= \frac{1}{2}( 180-\angle GDE)= \frac{1}{2} \angle EBG$$
Similarly
$$\angle FED=  \frac{1}{2} \angle FCE$$

In conclusion
$$\angle FEG =\frac{1}{2} (\angle FCE + \angle EBG)$$

Comment: The last line should have $\angle FCE$, not $\angle FEC$.

Comment: thx, I replaced it now

Comment: @J.Doe: how did you make this picture? What software?

Comment: @Arnaldo The software is called GeoGebra

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $a,b,c$, ($b$ is opposite to $x$ and $a$ is the up arc) those three arcs on the circle:

$$\frac{a+b-c}{2}=32$$
$$\frac{b+c-a}{2}=84$$

Sum both equations and get $b=32+84$ and then $x=b/2=58$

Comment: What theorem are you using? How did you get 84?

Comment: See this: item number 5. http://mathbitsnotebook.com/Geometry/Circles/CRAngles.html

Comment: $84$ is the thrid angle of the triangle $84=180-(64+32)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

It is an in-circle of the given triangle.Formed by corner angle bisectors. Angle chasing can find it.